# sql to doctrine query language

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

How I can write this sql to doctrine query language ([DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html))?

```
SELECT * 
FROM service 
WHERE service.id NOT IN (SELECT id_service FROM reclamation)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try use not exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM service 
WHERE NOT Exists (SELECT 1 FROM reclamation WHERE id_service = service.id)
```

Comment: you can find [query examples here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery(
             'SELECT s 
              FROM YourBundle:Service s
              WHERE s.id NOT IN 
                 ( SELECT s.idService FROM YourBundle:Reclamation r )'
            )->getResult();
```

If that deserves, you can use the old school way! [native-sql-with-docrtine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 122 near 'idService FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: I think you should check your syntax

Answer (score 0):

see the link  http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('s')
    ->from('Service s')
    ->where('s.id NOT IN (SELECT id_service FROM reclamation)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```